# Vuex stores state is undefined in console, but Vue tool is showing that are working properly

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I want to display my getters in web but in console.log i have undefined errors. but in vue dev tool my getters are working.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

my component code :

```
export default {
data: () => ({
  items: [
    { text: 'Real-Time', icon: 'mdi-clock' },
    { text: 'Audience', icon: 'mdi-account' },
    { text: 'Conversions', icon: 'mdi-flag' },
  ],
}),
computed: {
  Question(){
    return this.$store.getters.getQuest
  }
},
methods: {
  Next(){
    this.$store.commit('incrementIndex')
  }
},
```

}

and this my vuex :

```
 export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    question: [],
    index: 0
  },
  getters: {
    getQuest: state => {
      let a = state.question[state.index]
      let answer = [...a.incorrect_answers, a.correct_answer]
      return {
        question: a,
        answer: answer
      }
    }

  },
```

Comment: Can you add the error you are getting

Comment: @Vincent, try to provide sufficient information that'd be needed by others to understand your issue properly.

Comment: @Himanshu i just upload the error image

Comment: Check the length of `state.question` in your getter before blindly accessing its indexes. If it's empty, return a suitable default value

Comment: @Vincent Can you print the value of question array inside the getter to the console and see if it has incorrect_answers defined on it? If that's the issue simply put a check in your getter.

Comment: @Phil can you tell what is the name of a case like this? i want to learn it from youtube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the getter you need to check whether all information is loaded yet. So this is roughly what I'd do:

```
 export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    question: [],
    index: 0
  },
  getters: {
    getQuest: state => {
      let a = state.question[state.index]
      if (a){
       let answer = [...a.incorrect_answers, a.correct_answer]
       return {
        question: a,
        answer: answer
       }
      } else {
       return null
    }

  },
```

Comment: wow okay its work thank you, but can you tell me, what is the name of a case like this so i  can study it on youtube

Comment: wow okay its work thank you, but can you tell me, what is the name of a case like this so i  can study it on youtube

Comment: I have no idea. You have to go beyond youtube at some point. It seems this is it.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting undefined errors because initially **question** is an empty array. 
So **state.question[state.index]** is basically **undefined** 
And then you are trying to access property **incorrect_answers** of undefined which will not work and will give **undefined errors**